# Continuous Integration using GIT / BitBucket on a GIT controlled Intranet

Tags: php, git, netbeans, bitbucket

I had just implemented GIT Version Control for a Team of three people. We are managing to pull/push/fetch etc to our bitBucket repository. My only concern is how I should push live after we make an update to the repository.

On another server, I wrote a shell script to clone the repo into a directory so I would be able to test, but on the live server I cannot do the same since on some occasions I just have to push one file only.

Please note that our live server is inside a network and not accessible over the internet (thus I cannot use BitBucket's push service).

Comment: Yes my friend, as some people might suggest classes or functions to make the push via a scoket stream or something. i am open to any suggestion which works cost effective.
For Example: http://brandonsummers.name/blog/2012/02/10/using-bitbucket-for-automated-deployments/

Comment: quetzalcoat it explains that he is using Netbeans to develop php and using Git as a source control method.

Comment: Sorry but I guess Fairmutex just got the Hammer on the Nail.
To repeat, it explains that I am using NetBeans IDE to develop PHP and using Git as a source control method.
I Specified what language I'm using to let the community know that my server supports PHP...

Comment: Thank you vey much! I hope I didn't irritate you both. I just wanted to be perfectly sure that this edit was relevant.. I'll clear up my comments now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only advise I can give is to make sure that the local repository (which concentrates changes from the developers) is up to date and in shape before pushing.

Locally you can define your workflow. Perhaps the master repo, into which only official commits are taken, branches for each developer's work once it passes local tests, and each one does as they please on their machines. Or something fancier. There are suggestions on workflows, ranging from almost centralized to completely distributed, check them out. If you adopt one way of working, `git` won't stand in your way if you decide later to change it.

Comment: +1'd your answer.... I really like what you are describing as it enlightened some ideas. I will continue my research and post a reply back and choose an answer :)